# OpenAPI-Specification 2.0 a post with body AND header

Tags: yaml, swagger, restful-architecture, swagger-2.0

I want to send a object in a post but with a api key.

How can I describe this in [OpenAPI-Specification 2.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md)?

I tried this (a subset in yaml):

```
paths:
  /eau:
    post:
      tags:
        - Pets
      summary: Send a pet
      description: 'Send a pet'
      operationId: sendapet
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: pet
          description: Send a pet
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/pet'
        - in: header
          name: api_key
```

But at

```
- in: header
    name: api_key
```

I get the following error:

```
Schema error at paths['/pet'].post.parameters[1].in
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: body
Jump to line 36

Schema error at paths['/pet'].post.parameters[1]
should match exactly one schema in oneOf
Jump to line 36

Schema error at paths['/pet'].post.parameters[1]
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: in, name
Jump to line 36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the header parameter is missing `type`.

However, API keys are related to authentication/authorization, so they should be described using the `securityDefinitions` and `security` keywords instead of a header parameter:

```yaml
securityDefinitions:
  apiKey:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: api_key

security:
  - apiKey: []
```

More info: [API Keys](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/api-keys/)